# Pyspark MapOutputTrackerMaster Error while Running Dataproc Batch

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my pyspark serverless batch output log can see this warning

`ERROR MapOutputTrackerMaster: Asked to update map output for unknown shuffle 16`

`ERROR MapOutputTrackerMaster: Asked to update map output for unknown shuffle 17`

`ERROR MapOutputTrackerMaster: Asked to update map output for unknown shuffle 18`

**After this I can see my batch as succeeded but want to know does this lead to loss of data after the batch is completed?**